# How to set your default value in a constructor of iterators? C++

Tags: c++, dictionary, constructor, iterator

I'm doing a constructor for my iterator but I can't figure what's the default value

here's the declaration :

`const_iterator(typename map<TYPE, TYPE2>::const_iterator = ????? );`

It's a vector of maps, so my iterator will be a map iterator.
What would be the default value?

Cause when I do :
`HashMap<TYPE, TYPE2>::const_iterator i;`

It says that I have no appropriate default constructor.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to do here? Why do you need a default value for this constructor? What do you want to achieve from it? Something looks weird, but there's not much context.

Comment: What is this constructor supposed to do? Does it make sense for the parameter to have a default?

Comment: @awoodland I edited my question. I'm sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not going into why you would need a default value, I would suggest to use the default value of the map iterator (which is an invalid iterator)

```
 typedef typename map<TYPE, TYPE2>::const_iterator map_citer;
 const_iterator(map_citer param = map_citer());
                                //^^^^^^^^^^^
```

***Edit:***

Considering your edit, it seems that most logical in your situation would be to overload your constructor. Have two overloads, one that doesn't take anything (do what you think is best in that constructor) and your original one. That should do the trick :)

```
const_iterator(typename map<TYPE, TYPE2>::const_iterator);
const_iterator();
```